# Add a filter to a published Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

What I've done so far: made a fusion table that includes some categories that I'd like users to be able to filter results by (filters include locations and types).

My question: How do I that?

Comment: What have you learned about filtering on fusion tables so far? Have you seen these: https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171203?hl=en, https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2562121?hl=en? Have you tried anything in regards to filtering at all?

Comment: I found out how to convert my fusion tables into maps with filters. I used FusionTablesLayer Wizard (http://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesLayerWizard/src/index.html), but my new problem is I can't get that map to load because there's something wrong with how I'm inputing the Google Maps API

Answer (score 0):

You should look into this template/tool: http://derekeder.com/searchable_map_template/.

It's pretty well made template for setting up a searchable and filterable map with listings. It's fairly well documented on how to install and where to put the filter code, but if you get stuck it has an active Google Group for those that have questions.

*I would have made this a comment and not an answer since I'm just pointing you to another resource, but my rep isn't high enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Make Fusion Table
Step 2) Use this website: http://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesLayerWizard/src/index.html